# Property of the $\zeta := \exp(2\pi i/k)$ function.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, exponential-function, hilbert-spaces

Working on something I arrived at a point where I can conclude if the following is true:
Let $\zeta := \exp(2\pi i/k)$ with a $k\ge 1$ integer (if it helps it can be $k\ge 2$), and let $\mu$, $\nu$ be integers such that $\mu \not =\nu$ (mod $k$); then
$$\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\zeta^{(\mu - \nu)l} = 0$$

---

**Observation:** I think I found that if $\mu =\nu$ (mod $k$), then there exist $h\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\nu = \mu +hk$, so
$$\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\zeta^{(\mu - \nu)l} = \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \zeta^{-hkl}\zeta^{0} = \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \mbox{ exp}(2\pi i)^{hl} = \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} (-1)^{2hl} = \sum_{l=0}^{k-1}1=k$$

---

Could somebody please help me with proving or disproving the claim? I really have been struggling with it for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $q=\zeta^{\mu-\nu}$. Since $\mu\not\equiv\nu\pmod k$ we have $q\ne1$, so we can apply the geometric sum formula to get:$$\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}q^l=\frac{q^k-1}{q-1}$$
Now we have $q^k=\zeta^{(\mu-\nu)k}=1$, hence the sum equals $0$.

Comment: Thank you, hadn't thought of that. So the sum formula is true also for complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, it is also valid for complex numbers. Actually it holds in arbitrary rings although we would then need to rewrite it as $(q-1)(1+q+\dots+q^{k-1})=q^k-1$.